# My site flagged as unsafe by Smartscreen only in Microsoft Edge

Tags: magento-1.9, microsoft-edge, phishing, smartscreen

My Magento 1.9 webshop is marked as unsafe (phishing which is not true) in Microsoft Edge, if switch to IE and run Smart Screen security check it says all safe. 
And strangely only on one of my computers and therefore didn't bother much but also a customer complained about it today.

Anyone experienced this before and have a solution? Is there a way to check why a site is marked as unsafe by smartscreen?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my searching results, Below information may helpful to you.

> Q. If I am a website owner, how do I correct a warning on my legitimate site?
>
> A. You can immediately submit a request for a correction. Windows Defender SmartScreen has a built-in, web-based feedback system in place to help customers and website owners report any potential false warnings as quickly as possible. In Windows Internet Explorer, from a red warning, click More information then Report that this site contains no threats. This will take you to a feedback page where you can indicate you are a site owner or representative. Follow the instructions and provide the information on this site to submit a site for review...

Reference:

[Resolving “This website has been reported as unsafe” (Windows Defender SmartScreen)](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/185558/resolving-this-website-has-been-reported-as-unsafe-windows-defender-smartscre)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have already submited it for a review but I'm more interested if there is a way to see why they suspected my site to be phishing. It's the second time they have done this and I would like to prevent a third time if possible.

Answer (score 0):

**Q.
If I am a website owner, what can I do to help minimize the chance of my website being flagged by Windows Defender SmartScreen?**

A.
There are several things you can do that can help minimize the chance of your site being flagged as suspicious. Think of these as best practices or optimal website design ethics.

If you ask users for personal information, use HTTPS with a valid, unexpired server certificate issued by a trusted certification authority.

Make sure that your webpage doesn't expose any cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities. Protect your site by using anti-cross-site scripting functions such as those provided by the Microsoft Anti-Cross Site Scripting library.

Use the fully-qualified domain name rather than an IP-literal address. (This means a URL should look like "microsoft.com" and not "207.46.19.30.")

Don't encode or tunnel your URLs unnecessarily. If you don't know what this means, you probably aren't doing it.

If you post external or third-party hosted content, make sure that the content is secure and from a known and trusted source.

Reference:

[Windows Defender SmartScreen Frequently Asked Questions](https://feedback.smartscreen.microsoft.com/smartscreenfaq.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. I have tried my very best to find and remove all my http links and remove or replace them with https. XSS I'm not sure if I have, maybe my Amasty Google reCaptha or card payment with ePay counts as that? Otherwise everything is just standard Magento. Is there any easy way to check?

Comment: To check for cross site scripting vulnerabilities you can refer link below. https://www.google.com/intl/ko_BJ/about/appsecurity/learning/xss/ There are some 3rd party sites available who let you to check this. You can try to check for those sites.

Comment: Great, thanks! I will try this as soon as I'm at my computer.

Comment: If you think that you got the answer for your question than you can consider to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer for this thread. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

In MS Edge browser there's an option to "report file as safe". After clicking it - select the "I'm a website owner" option and fill the false-positive form.

[image]